# Postgres and Word Clouds

Tags: postgresql, function, word-cloud

I would like to know if its possible to create a Postgres function to scan some table rows and create a table that contains `WORD` and `AMOUNT` (frequency)? My goal is to use this table to create a Word Cloud.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Can you provide rules to find `WORD` in any text? Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Please take a look on this: http://videos.web-03.net/diagramacao/eduardo/mrbool/builtagcloud/figura04.png

Comment: So how does one specifies `WORDS` like `Drupal` and/or `Open Source` from the picture above? Question needs more precise input.

Comment: There is a row table, with a TEXT data type, that contains texts and expressions. What I need is a postgres function to separate row texts into words, count them and generate a table with this informations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way, but it can be slow (depending on your table size). You can split your text into an array:

```
SELECT string_to_array(lower(words), ' ') FROM table;
```

With those arrays, you can use `unnest` to aggregate them:

```
WITH words AS (
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array(lower(words), ' ')) AS word
    FROM table
)
SELECT word, count(*) FROM words
GROUP BY word;
```

This is a simple way of doing that and, has some issues, like, it only split words by space not punctuation marks.

Other, and probably **better option**, is to use [PostgreSQL full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-intro.html).

Comment: Well done. Your idea seems to work well. But now I have just one problem. I'm using MS-Access as a front end and the text field that I need to scan contains html codes, like ,<div> </div> that need to be discarted. Do you have some idea?

Comment: I've a function to stri html code here: http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/148 With that your solutions works almost perfectly

Comment: You can simply use a regexp to remove the HTML tags: `regexp_replace(words, '<[^>]*>', '', 'g')`.

Comment: Perfect! But, What I have to do to strip html expressions like &quot ?

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party but I also needet this and wanted to use full text search.
Which conveniently removes html tags.

So basically you convert the text to a `tsvector` and then use `ts_stat`:

```sql
select word, nentry 
from ts_stat($q$ 
    select to_tsvector('simple', '<div id="main">a b c <b>b c</b></div>') 
$q$)
order by nentry desc
```

Result:

```
|word|nentry|
|----|------|
|c   |2     |
|b   |2     |
|a   |1     |
```

But this does not scale well, so here is what I endet up with:

Setup:

```sql
-- table with a gist index on the tsvector column
create table wordcloud_data (
    html text not null,
    tsv tsvector not null
);
create index on wordcloud_data using gist (tsv);

-- trigger to update the tsvector column
create trigger wordcloud_data_tsvupdate 
    before insert or update on wordcloud_data 
    for each row execute function tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'pg_catalog.simple', html);

-- a view for the wordcloud
create view wordcloud as select word, nentry from ts_stat('select tsv from wordcloud_data') order by nentry desc;
```

Usage:

```sql
-- insert some data
insert into wordcloud_data (html) values 
    ('<div id="id1">aaa</div> <b>bbb</b> <i attribute="ignored">ccc</i>'), 
    ('<div class="class1"><span>bbb</span> <strong>ccc</strong> <pre>ddd</pre></div>');
```

After that your `wordcloud` view should look like this:

```
|word|nentry|
|----|------|
|ccc |2     |
|bbb |2     |
|ddd |1     |
|aaa |1     |
```

Bonus features:
Replace `simple` with for example `english` and postgres will strip out stop words and do stemming for you.